# FeignClient API with different response class

Tags: java, error-handling, jhipster, spring-cloud-feign, fallback

I am using Jhipster. I have a yaml file, then generate java code using jhipster openapi-client. It generate several files, including the all the model class needed (to contain the request and response).

**DefaultApiClient**

```
@FeignClient(name="${default.name:default}", url="${default.url:https://test.api.com/testing}", configuration = ClientConfiguration.class)
public interface DefaultApiClient extends DefaultApi {
}
```

**DefaultApi**

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2021-01-22T14:50:31.377193700+08:00[Asia/Singapore]")

@Validated
@Api(value = "Default", description = "the Default API")
public interface DefaultApi {

    /**
     * POST /req/v1 : This is the request
     *
     * @param authorization JWT header for authorization (required)
     * @param body  (required)
     * @return successful operation (status code 200)
     *         or server cannot or will not process the request (status code 400)
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "This is the request", nickname = "Verification", notes = "", response = ResponseType.class, authorizations = {
        @Authorization(value = "clientID")
    }, tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation", response = ResponseType.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "server cannot or will not process the request", response = ServiceMessagesType.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/req/v1",
        produces = "application/json",
        consumes = "application/json",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<ResponseType> Verification(@ApiParam(value = "JWT header for authorization" ,required=true, defaultValue="Bearer REPLACE_THIS_KEY") @RequestHeader(value="Authorization", required=true) String authorization,@ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true )  @Valid @RequestBody RequestType body);

}
```

I can manage to get the response successfully, but the problem appear when I send a false request, It will response with and Bad Request 400 and crash my program.

As you can see on the swagger annotation @ApiResponse, it return different class.
I am really confuse with it. My question is:

1. Just for confirm, @ApiResponse is only for documentation, right? Does this code affect the program like when it return code 400, the response will automatically be ServiceMessageType class?
2. How can I handle different response class? As you can see in the function deffinition, ResponseEntity Verification, it will return ResponseType as the body of ResponseEntity. But when I send an error request to this Api, this Api will return ServiceMessageType. And fyi, the code 400 will give my program an error says "failed and no fallback available" so I think I need an error handle to do it.
3. For no.2, I already search for the solution in several source
   https://programmer.group/feign-call-error-failed-and-no-fallback-available.html
   but I don't really get it. I use the fallbackFactory, and it can handle the 400 code exception. But I still really confuse about how to return different response class. And I get the result not in correct structure, as the link said:

> By implementing FallbackFactory, you can get the exception thrown by the service in the create method. However, please note that the exception here is encapsulated by Feign, and the exception thrown by the original method cannot be seen directly in the exception information. The abnormal information obtained is as follows: status 500 reading TestService#addRecord(ParamVO); content: {"success":false,"resultCode":null,"message":"/ by zero","model":null,"models":[],"pageInfo":null,"timelineInfo":null,"extra":null,"validationMessages":null,"valid":false}

> To illustrate, in this example, the interface return information of the service provider will be uniformly encapsulated in the user-defined class Result, and the content is the above content: {"success":false,"resultCode":null,"message":"/ by zero","model":null,"models":[],"pageInfo":null,"timelineInfo":null,"extra":null,"validationMessages":null,"valid":false}

Please explain to me how it work, or you can give me a link about how it works, I will really appreciate the help.